# PHP: is_array is returning false when it should not

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have this simple one line code:

```
$thisUserName = is_array($user) ? $user->name : $user;
```

Here, `$thisUserName` is giving by `$user`, means, the condition `is_array` is returning false, even if `print_r` is showing that `$user` is an array.

Any idea, anybody ?

Thanks.

PS. I tried changing that to `echo is_array($user) ? 'yes' : 'no'` and it is echoing no.

EDIT:

print_r($user) gives

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 169
    [name] => Cedric
    [username] => pulpfiction
    [email] => xxx@gmail.com
    [password] => c22601b4ed1ac11a80955d6c0eeb1933
    [password_clear] => 
    [usertype] => Registered
    [block] => 0
    [sendEmail] => 0
    [gid] => 18
    [registerDate] => 2013-01-30 11:12:10
    [lastvisitDate] => 2013-02-24 19:45:45
    [activation] => 
    [params] => 

    [aid] => 1
    [guest] => 0
)
```

Comment: Is $user an array or an instantiated object? Because $user->name should error is $user is an array

Comment: You do realize that the `->` operator belongs to objects, not arrays, right? Maybe you need `is_object() instead? Or maybe you need to use `[]` instead of `->`.

Comment: var_dump($user) shows what?

Comment: if you want to check that user in array then maybe it should be in_array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$user` is an object not an array. `print_r()` will still output it all nice looking, but if you look closely at the output you will see not everything will say array, it will have have the object listed. You should be using [is_object()](https://www.php.net/is_object)

```
$thisUserName = is_object($user) ? $user->name : $user;
```

Comment: Jackpot Cryptic. How did you guess that $user would be an object here ?

Comment: @Jeremy - the `->` syntax is for objects. Arrays use `=>`

Comment: @Jeremy `$user->name` is the property `name` of the object `$user`

Comment: I would prefer to use `instanceof` to confirm the actual class of the object, rather than just `is_object()`.

Comment: what do you mean SDC? instanceof can check if that's an array or object ?

Comment: @Jeremy if you can post the output of `print_r` @SDC can provide you with a working example using `instanOf` but we need to know the name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

`is_array()` checks whether the variable is an array.

However, your code immediately after it is `$user->name`, which implies that you are actually expecting it to be an object. `is_array()` will not return true for objects.

If you want to test if it's an object, you could use [`is_object()`](https://www.php.net/is_object) instead of `is_array()`.

However, it would be even better to check if it's an object of the type you expect, in which case you could use [`instanceof`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php#language.operators.type) eg:

```
$thisUserName = ($user instanceof myUserClass) ? $user->name : $user
```

(where 'myUserClass' is the class name of your user class, obviously)

Hope that helps.

[EDIT]

In a good system, one should know the class name that is expected for any given object, and use `instanceof` to verify it.

But if you don't know the class name to expect then `is_object()` will suffice.

(You can find out the class name of an object using `get_class()`; that might be worthwhile for your own purposes to learn about the system you're using (Drupal?), but there's little point using `get_class` and `intanceof` together in this context to actually test the object; just stick with `is_object()`)

Comment: edited answer to answer @Jeremy's confusion about not knowing the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using object ,Then try this example

```
    <?php
    $user->name='my_name';
    echo (is_object($user)) ?$user->name:$user;
    ?>
```

//Result : my_name